# why can't I scroll Wikipedia pages horizontally?

Tags: browser

I have found that Wikipedia pages with image content larger than my Droid X's screen size cannot be resized or scrolled horizontally, this means that these pictures are only partially visible.
obviously this is very frustrating.

I have already tried different browsers (Dolphin, Boat) and have also tried different User Agents (iPhone, iPad, and even Desktop) with no effect.

I should also note that I have the exact same problem when viewing Facebook photos in the Browser.

The only thing that **sometimes** works is rotating the aspect ratio to landscape, and then only if the horizontal size of the photo is less than ~850px. horizontal scrolling and zooming is still disabled.

Strangely - googling this problem returns *no* results! so maybe I'm the only one with this problem???

somehow, I doubt it tho.

does anyone have a solution? or even an explanation?

Comment: Did you use the mobile version of wikipedia or the standard version?

Comment: I've seen this too, so it's not specific to your device.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because you are viewing Wikipedia's mobile site.

On the bottom of every page there should be a link to "View this page on regular Wikipedia."  Tap it, and after the page refreshes you should be able to resize/scroll it normally.  If you like, you can also tap the "Permanently disable mobile site" link to prevent being redirected to the limited mobile version of Wikipedia.

Comment: Yep.  I *hate* that the browser doesn't let you zoom on mobile sites.